# Netbeans PHP breakpoint variable value "Evaluating..."

Tags: php, variables, breakpoints, netbeans-8

When I set a breakpoint in my PHP code I cannot see the content of a string variable because in the variables Value column it says "Evaluating...". What can be done to prevent this from happening? What is this, a timing problem? Can it be fixed with another setting?

I have seen this before but now I really need to know the value to find out my error.

I could isolate the problem and apparently it has to do with the result of PHP implode() that somehow takes too long or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did not use Watches to evaluate the variable that was pending. I have no Watches and Balloon Evaluation set. I only use the Debug Variable display. I discovered that in my case the "Maximum Data Length" setting was too small. The variable value went beyond this limit. I was able to fix the issue by raising the limit.

Comment: Mine was 2048 (probably by default). 4096 worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: And to clarify, the "Maximum Data Length" setting is at NetBeans > Tools > Options > PHP > Debugging > "Maximum Data Length" (also shown in the screenshot here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39963917/470749 ). Mine was 2048 (probably by default). 16384 worked for me just now for my purposes where I had a huge JSON string. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Open netbeans, to to `Tools -> Options -> PHP`

When you use Watches, then make sure `Watches and Balloon Evaluation` is checked:

[image]

Also make sure that variables you want to evaluate don't hit the "Maximum Data Length" limit. Adjust this when necessary.

Comment: There was nothing in the question about Watches.  The other answer is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a white since this question was posted, but as it came up as the top result when I was searching for an answer and none are correct - here is the correct answer.

Change the tools -> options -> php -> debugging ->maximum data length to a bigger number.  I used 50000 before longer strings became visible.

[See a screenshot of the settings here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNKmO.png)